# Use 微积分 to mean 'tiny'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Just reading 人类简史, translated into Chinese by 林俊宏。

微积分: calculus

I know very little about 微积分, except that it is a way to divide by zero and still get an answer!

But in this text, 微积分 seems to mean tiny. Or what does it mean?

人类深深迷恋着我们自己的高智能，于是一心认为智力当然是越高越好。
但如果真是如此，猫科动物也经过演化，为什么没有会**微积分**的猫？
究竟为什么，在整个动物界， 只有人属演化出了比例如此庞大思考器官？

Answer (score 3):

It just means "calculus".

The text roughly translates to:

> We *Homo sapiens* are infatuated with our own intellectual capabilities, and unanimously consider intelligence as an advantage. However, consider if this is really the case - [*Felis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felis) have also undergone evolution, so why aren't there any cats which can do **calculus**? Why, in the whole animal kingdom, have only *Homo sapiens* evolved large organs capable of deep thought?

Comment: Oops! Bothered by our cat, I missed the 会！I've read, brains, even cat brains, solve extremely complex differential equations every time we catch something. Cats can do it!

Answer (score 1):

为什么没有会微积分的猫？- Why there is no cat that can perform calculus?

"Calculus" - an advanced mathematic operation usually taught in the college-level class to students in science majors.